# На рабочем столе есть ярлыки типо хрома но их как таковых нету файлами типа lnk

Tags: windows, desktop

Помогите делаю программу для очистки пк от всякого мусора на C#. На рабочем столе есть ярлыки типо хрома но их как таковых нету файлами типа lnk. Мне нужно удалить эти ярлыки но я не понимаю как откуда они вообще и почему на рабочем столе  в файловом менеджере смотрел ничего нет показывает
Открываю рабочий стол просто не через файловый менеджер показывает что ярлыки есть

Comment: Они либо в папке рабочего стола текущего пользователя, либо в папке *общего* рабочего стола

Comment: Спасибо огромное вы гений!